# Gazebo 1.2.5 Groovy tutorials, spawning models, setting paths?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-1.2, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Can I get some pointers how to set up my PATHS in ROS so I can properly use Gazebo (currently I can only start my empty.world, and cannot add my models) ? Or what else do I need to set up in order to use Gazebo under Groovy.

My current paths look like this:

GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_simulator/pr2_gazebo/test:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/share/gazebo-1.2
GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11345
GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/pr2_simulator/pr2_gazebo_benchmarks/lib:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/gazebo-1.2/plugins:
GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI=http://gazebosim.org/models

I am not being able to spawn anything (only with the *SetFromString()* function) , answering [these](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/433/gzfactory-spawning-not-working-in-gazebo-12/) questions would really help me, or updating the tutorials for using Gazebo with Groovy.

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/443/gazebo-1.2.5-groovy-tutorials,-spawning-models,-setting-paths-??/) by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 2108 on 2012-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is the setup.sh that we use for the DRC simulator project. It creates the paths between ROS and Gazebo. Note that this file is parsed used cmake to produce the final result.
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/d4266379422bececc55afaaae2cbe961f66486e0/cmake/setup.sh.in?at=default

I've also added a [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/288/write-tutorial-on-using-ros-with-gazebo) to bitbucket

---

Originally posted by [natepak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57/natepak/) with karma: 111 on 2012-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1